# Intellij copyright profile velocity template variable don't work

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to configure my Intellij IDEA IDE to update all my project files with our company copyright header. The velocity template variables don't appear to work. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here's what I've set the copyright text to:

Copyright (c) MyCompany $year.

It simply places '$year' verbatim into my Java files!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this in your copyright statement inside of IDEA:

```
$today.year
```

Comment: Find more possible vars here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/copyright-profiles.html?origin=old_help

Answer (score 0):

I think inteljidea not support variable in Copyright 
Even you use to File Headers (Templates - java) should use ${YESR}